# How to share web content to mobile?

Tags: mobile

I am newbie. I built a site. But I am not know how to share web content to mobile? I mean add some button, user click the button, share site url or content to android, iphone or even basic symbian system.

Should I make a contact to telephone company for a SMS service? Or only some 3rd part service on Internet? Is there any tutorial for reference or any software? Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by share site URL? Do you mean when a user clicks the button they can email a 'friend' and send the URL of the page they're on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view any website with any platform which has a browser and, providing the website has been designed to comply with the browser, there should be no issue.

Javascript and flash can causes issues on certain mobile devices though, so test first if you feel this type of surfer is common/important etc.

As for sharing the URL by email, that is done in code as you would do on a website (regardless of browser because ultimately they are still viewing a website). As for third party plugins for SMS, it first depends on the language/technology you are using as to what service(s) are available. **EDIT:** You could try http://mashable.com/2008/04/19/send-text-messages/ to give you an idea.

If you want to just detect the device, then in ASP.NET (C#) you can do something in the PageLoad() method

```
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/mobile.aspx");          
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I mean my site is not a mobile site, it just a normal site, I wanna ask is there a method send defined content to a mobile (like some SMS service, site to moblie?)

Comment: OK, the question is not clear. Are you saying that for each page they visit, you want to send a SMS with the content? I have updated my answer to provide example code

Comment: thanks again. Now the only think I still not clear, how to send messages from web servers to mobile. Should I contact to telephone company or some 3rd part service company who could provide service send SMS from Internet to mobile?

Comment: The answer is in the body